# MVC error including/excluding view

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have this situation.
Three 'section' elements, on each one i load a view

```
                <section class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <?= $this->load->view('folder/view1',NULL,TRUE); ?>
                </section>


                <section class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <?= $this->load->view('folder/view2',NULL,TRUE); ?>
                </section>


                <section class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <?= $this->load->view('folder/view3',NULL,TRUE); ?>
                </section>
```

I can delete, move or edit the view on top and the one on the bottom, but not the view in the middle, if I do so, the browser return me a blank page without errors. 
I have enabled all error logs, there is nothing.
Every single view got their tags and php code perfectly idented and closed.
That one is the only one giving me troubles.

What could be the problem?

Comment: does problem really resides with having 3 loads? or only this one `$this->load->view('folder/view2',NULL,TRUE)` is problem? I mean if you move that one at the top, and remove rest 2, will it show blank? or not?

Comment: In any order the only one wich throws the blank page is deleting te view2. In any order if i delete or change the other views it works

Comment: so problem is in `view`, it's also interesting what's inside that views, maybe something strange there?

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was on the controller...
I will post it and if no one find the solution as a good one for someone else, i´ll delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three includes i´ve posted before are inside another one,

I save the view as cache, for this, I difined the result as a variable and send in to the browser.

```
$string=$this->load->view('main/mainview',$data,TRUE);
echo $string;
```

but i skiped an `echo $string` to send it to the browser, because the last parameter of load->view is false for default but in this way it must be TRUE

i´m still confused about what changes view2 does to avoid this parameter, but after solving it i can edit all file properly.

If someone considers this answer as useless i will delete it as fast as possible
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use firebug/ console to see if the view resource is found, or something else related to fetching the asset.

Comment: i'm using firebug, it shows status 'ok' response but nothing on response, the page is full blank whithout errors and firebugs show no error, but neither response

Comment: What are the contents of view2?  Maybe the other views are somehow dependent on it, or view2 is has the <!doctype> tag or loads some required scripts, etc.

Comment: There is no doctype or scripts is a `<ul></ul>` with `<li>` elements loaded with php, the php start and end are correctly defined, the tags are closed.